# Error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-theme

Getting a runtime time error of NullPointerException.The code includes a toolbar a navigation drawer.I even tried it with NoActionBar.
theme used is

```
 <style name="Theme.Hospital" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Runtime error
toolbar is returning null value

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
 ComponentInfo{com.vrushali.hospital/com.vrushali.hospital.MainActivity3}: 
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
 androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object 
 reference.
```

Used My Code is here
have a look at the code and please resolve it

```
 public class MainActivity3 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout drawer_layout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView navigation_view;
    private TextView nav_fullname;
    private  TextView nav_email,nav_contact,nav_type;
    private DatabaseReference userRef;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        drawer_layout= findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Patient Portal");
        navigation_view = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity3.this,drawer_layout,
                toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_closed);
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        nav_fullname =navigation_view.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nav_fullname);
        nav_email =navigation_view.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nav_email);
        nav_contact =navigation_view.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nav_contact);
        nav_type =navigation_view.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nav_type);
        userRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    String name= snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    nav_fullname.setText(name);
                    String email= snapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
                    nav_email.setText(email);
                    String phonenumber= snapshot.child("phonenumber").getValue().toString();
                    nav_contact.setText(phonenumber);
                    String type= snapshot.child("type").getValue().toString();
                    nav_type.setText(type);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Well presumably `getSupportActionBar()` is returning null.

Comment: how do i resolve it

Comment: Well have you stepped through the code in the debugger? You're calling `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` - is `toolbar` non-null (not just in theory, but have you *verified* that it's non-null)?

Answer (score 0):

The function `getSupportActionBar()` is returning null. The most common reason for this error is because you are hiding the action bar with `requestWindowFeature(<whatEverYouUsed>)` function. Or because you are calling `getSupportActionBar()` before it is instantiated. For instance maybe it is before the `super.onCreate()` call?

There are many other reasons but without seeing the code its just guess work

Comment: i aint using requestWindowFeature()

Comment: getSupportActionBar is annotated as null how do I resolve this

Comment: super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
drawer_layout= findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

There are two many variables and i dont know what they are so its still just guess work. The good news is that the error i in the first 5 lines somewhere.

I can only assume its the variables in one of these two functions
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

or the toolbar variable is in fact null

Comment: it was a bug it got resolved by itself even i dont know how.